# Python : How to pass XML element as an argument

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file which looks like:

```
<root>
  <product>
  ...multiple tags
  </product>
  <product>
  ...multiple tags
  </product>
  .
  .
  .
</root>
```

There are multiple products in the file, each having a set of tags. I want to pass the XML corresponding to a product as an argument for a HTTP request. I looked through [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) but could not find how to "get" a child element.

Could someone please help. Thanks

**EDIT:** I have tried using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print child       //also tried child.text
```

But I get the following output and not the XML corresponding to each child:

```
<Element 'product' at 0xb729328c>
<Element 'product' at 0xb7293d0c>
<Element 'product' at 0xb72987ec>
<Element 'product' at 0xb729b2cc>
<Element 'product' at 0xb729bcec>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "XML request"?

Comment: HTTp request actually, giving the xml as a parameter

Comment: You seem a bit confused. You *do* have the XML corresponding to each child, in the `Element` objects. You've just printed them, rather than actually dumping their text content with `ET.dumps(child)`, but you don't actually want to pass that dump to the function, you want the child element you already have, which you can manipulate.

Comment: use `tostring`: `for child in root: x = ET.tostring(child); print x`

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I think this should work. Thanks a lot.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you have an XML file and you want to extract the data for each `<product />` element, as an XML string which you can use in a HTTP request. By extending what @nrathaus has already said I hope to give a slightly more complete answer to your question.

We can get a list of [`Element`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) objects, corresponding to the `<product />` elements as follows:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('products.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
product_elements = root.findall('product')
```

Then to turn each of these elements into an XML string use [`ElementTree.tostring`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring). For example:

```
for product_element in product_elements:
    print(ElementTree.tostring(product_element))
```

---

### Example

*products.xml*

```
<products>
  <product>
    <name>First product</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Second product</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Third product</name>
  </product>
</products>
```

*test.py*

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('products.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
product_elements = root.findall('product')

for product_element in product_elements:
    print(ElementTree.tostring(product_element))
```

*Output*

```
/tmp/xml$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
/tmp/xml$ python test.py 
<product>
    <name>First product</name>
  </product>

<product>
    <name>Second product</name>
  </product>

<product>
    <name>Third product</name>
  </product>
```

Answer (score 1):

You usually do something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
root.findall('product')
```

The result from root.findall will return all the `product` items (as an array), so you can do:

```
for product in root.findall('product'):
```

Would go through all the child items

Comment: I can use `for child in root` as well. But that gives me some sort of code, `print child` = `<Element 'product' at 0xb729328c>`. I want the XML under product. Any way of doing that?

Comment: You want the XML or the object?

Comment: How about using [itertext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext)

Comment: I want the XML under each child

Comment: @MaxSpencer : I've looked through this link, but it doesn't mention how I can get the XML corresponding to a child element.

Comment: Just add `dump(..)` instead of `print`